# Create Sharepoint 2007 user

Tags: c#, sharepoint, active-directory

I am trying to create Sharepoint 2007 users through c#. I begin by adding them into our AD server, which is tied to our SP server. The users appear in the AD, as well as within the SP user directory. However, if you try to log into the Sharepoint site with this account, it will not allow you to.

In order to use the account on Sharepoint, you must first manually log onto the Windows domain via the standard windows login. Once you have logged onto the domain, the SP version of the account becomes 'active'. Is there anyway to stop this behavior and simply allow users to log onto the SP site without having to manually log them onto a machine first?

Comment: perhaps the user needs a SQL Server User Account and Password.. have you tried that.. but I am thinking SharePoint 2010.. so I know there are some brutal differences between 2007 & 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. You can create a user in Sharepoint and they are created properly, but if you set the user password to "Expire on first login" within Active Directory, then you will be unable to log onto the Sharepoint site until you reassign a new password to that account. By not setting the "expire password" property, you can create users and log onto the Sharepoint site immediately.

Thanks for the other solutions, I wish i was using SP2010!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is call EnsureUser which takes a regular AD user and turns them into one which is registered in SP. (ie so you can get a SPUser object for the user) Take a look here for how to do this:
http://blog.myitechnology.com/2009/06/right-way-to-spwebensureuser.html

Comment: That is what I am looking for, unfortunately I am using SP2007 which is a huge headache compared to SP2010.

Comment: yeah its a bit of a pain, this particular thing should be the same in 07 as 2010. I found WSPBuilder make sp2007 a bit easier but its nothing compared to the new tooling.